# Three.js: Why does the size of CanvasRenderer affect performance on iPhone5s' browsers(chrome, safari)

Tags: ios, three.js

I am trying to use Three.js to make some graphics. At the beginning stage, I found out: till now on ios7.0, I cannot use WebGL. So instead, I use CanvasRenderer. However, it seems that the size of CanvasRenderer will seriously affect the performance. Could someone give share some thoughts? Or provide a good resolution for CanvasRenderer on ios devices?

Note: I displayed the resolution of chrome on the iPhone5s: 980x1544.

If I set resolution to 640*1024, it works fine.

If I use smaller resolution: (window.innerWidth/2 , window.innerHeight/2), that works fine as well.

However, if I use full width and full height, the cube will not display. Even if I set height to (640,1025), the spinning cube will be really slow.

My question is : **how does the size of CanvasRenderer impact on the performance?** (Specifically for iPhone5 browsers in this case)

The following is the simple code I wrote to render a cube:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);
document.getElementById("debug").innerHTML = window.innerWidth + " " + window.innerHeight; 

renderer = webglAvailable() ? new THREE.WebGLRenderer() : new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize(640, 1024);
document.getElementById("body").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1,1,1);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 10;


var render = function () {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);

    cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
    cube.rotation.y += 0.1;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);
};

render();
```

For reference, you could try to use your iPhone to load these two pages. You can easily see the performance difference.

Resolution 640*1024:  http://shawnfandev.com/Testing/workingResolution/Cube.php

Resolution 640*1200:  http://shawnfandev.com/Testing/higherResolution/Cube.php

Any thoughts is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a simple simulation that can change resolution and calculates FPS.

The simulation renders 100 cubes to lower FPS to make it easy to compare.

FPS monitor is provided by [stats.js](https://github.com/mrdoob/stats.js/).

[This is jsfiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/Lhtoo1h2/3/)

HTML:

```
<div id="renderer"></div>
<div id="input_fileds">
    width: <input type="text" id="width" value="200">
    height: <input type="text" id="height" value="200">
</div>
```

javascript:

```
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(40, 1, 0.1, 1000);
var renderer = new THREE.CanvasRenderer();
renderer.setSize(200, 200);

container = document.getElementById('renderer');
document.body.appendChild(container);


container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

stats = new Stats();
stats.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
stats.domElement.style.top = '0px';
container.appendChild(stats.domElement);


var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(.3, .3, .3);
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0x00ff00});
var cubes = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    cube.position.x = Math.random() * 6 - 3;
    cube.position.y = Math.random() * 6 - 3;
    cubes.push(cube);
    scene.add(cube);
}

camera.position.z = 10;

var render = function() {
    cubes.forEach(function(cube) {
        cube.rotation.x += 0.1;
        cube.rotation.y += 0.1;
    });

    stats.update();
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    setTimeout(render, 1000 / 60);
};
render();

var width_input = document.getElementById('width');
var height_input = document.getElementById('height');
width_input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    resize();
});
height_input.addEventListener("keyup", function() {
    resize();
});

function resize() {
    camera.aspect = width_input.value / height_input.value;
    camera.updateProjectionMatrix();
    renderer.setSize(width_input.value, height_input.value);
}
```

css:

```
#renderer{
    margin-top:50px;
}
#renderer canvas{
    background-color: #000000;
}
#input_fileds{
    position:fixed !important;
    top:0px;
    padding-left:100px;
}
#stats{
    position:fixed !important;
}
```

Result on my iPhone5s

19 FPS on 600x600

19 FPS on 800x800

19 FPS on 1000x1000

19 FPS on 1024x1024

5 FPS on 1025x1025

FPS and resolution are not directly proportional to each other, but when resolution is greater than some point, FPS falls sharply.

Comment: Good information. According to your last sentence, I assume you are suggesting: we could only use lower resolution to maintain a reasonable FPS. Thanks.